# create a channel on catch.error instead of dms

Tags: discord.js

i am tring to do that every time someone that joins my server blocks dms the bot will open a channel and send a verify link instead of a dm
what I stuck on (store the channel and stuff like that)

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
        const linkId = pool.createLink(member.id);
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('reCAPTCHA Verification')
        .setDescription(`To gain access to this server you must solve a captcha. The link will expire in 15 minutes.\nhttp://${domain == '' ? 'localhost:8050' : domain}/verify/${linkId}`)
        .setColor('YELLOW');
        channel = client.channels.cache.get(`${logschannel}`);
        channel.send('user has joined if you dont get another message in a few minutes please check if the user has verifyed ');
        member.send(embed).catch(() => {message.guild.channels .create(member.id, { type: "text" }), channel.send('@here'); const errore = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('reCAPTCHA Verification')
            .setDescription(`The user with the id ${member.id} is blocking dms please check on that!`)
            .setColor('RED')
            channel.send(errore)})
```

what I had

```
        client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
        const linkId = pool.createLink(member.id);
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('reCAPTCHA Verification')
        .setDescription(`To gain access to this server you must solve a captcha. The link will expire in 15 minutes.\nhttp://${domain == '' ? 'localhost:8050' : domain}/verify/${linkId}`)
        .setColor('YELLOW');
        channel = client.channels.cache.get(`${logschannel}`);
        channel.send('user has joined if you dont get another message in a few minutes please check if the user has verifyed ');
        member.send(embed).catch(() => {channel.send('@here'); const errore = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('reCAPTCHA Verification')
            .setDescription(`The user with the id ${member.id} is blocking dms please check on that!`)
            .setColor('RED')
            channel.send(errore)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the channel you can just use `GuildChannelManager#create` (aka guild.channels.create).

```js
member.guild.channels.create(`${member.author.username}-verification`, {
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: member.author.id,
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
        {
            id: member.guild.id,
            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
    ]
});
```

To send a message to the channel there are two ways you can do it.

**A: Store the channel object.**

```js
const verifyChannel = member.guild.channels.create(`channel`);
verifyChannel.send('Message!')
```

**B: Use .then() as creating as channel returns a promise.**

```js
member.guild.channels.create(`channel`)
    .then(chan => {
        chan.send('Message!');
    });
```

Comment: thx, and if you can help i needed to store it to for the bot to send the link

Comment: Edited my post to help you, I'd recommend just doing option B.